# Rdlc report viewer expression comparison doesn't work

Tags: c#, expression, field, rdlc

```
=SWITCH(Fields!DES.Value="ZERO","8pt",Fields!DES.Value="Head 1 Pin 1 - Hold Position - Last (mm)","3pt",Fields!DES.Value="Electrode Change","8pt",Fields!CP.Value < "1.33","8pt")
```

This is my rdlc Expression. First parts works fine but at the end of switch:

```
Fields!CP.Value < "1.33","8pt"
```

Doesn't work. I have already tried "1,33" and 1.33

Comment: Fields!CP.Value is float at database: 
1,1805730812124295

Comment: Try converting the value like this: CDbl(Fields!CP.Value) < 1.33

Comment: I tried, that didn't work either :(

Comment: CDbl(Fields!CP.Value) < "1.33","8pt"
CDbl(Fields!CP.Value) < "1,33","8pt"
CDbl(Fields!CP.Value) < 1.33,"8pt"

I have tried three of these didnt work.
What is wrong :S